# Executing Func delegates in user defined order

Tags: c#, mvvm, func

I create some custom Funcs, and then adding them to a list of Funcs called Operators, as such:

```
...
    Func<Vector3, Vector3> Move1MFunc = (v) => v.Z == 0 ? v.Add(1, 0, 1) : v.Subtract(1, 0, 1);

    Func<Vector3, Vector3> Move2MFunc = (v) => v.Z == 0 ? v.Add(2, 0, 1) : v.Subtract(2, 0, 1);

    protected List<Func<Vector3, Vector3>> Operators { get; set; }
...
```

In some other method, I am iterating through the Operators list and executing each delegate as such:

```
    protected IEnumerable<Vector3> GetChildrenStates(Vector3 parentState)
    {
        foreach (var op in Operators)
        {
            // Get a child using the current operator
            var possibleChild = op(parentState);
            ...
```

Right now each delegate is being executed based on its order in the list. I would like the user to be able to define the order in which each function should be executed (in relation to each other). I would be presenting the user some strings which would represent each delegate and in code behind link them to the delegates themselves(?). I'm using MVVM.

I have tried doing this using attributes, but from what I found out attributes do not support Funcs.

I can't seem to think of another solution, hence I'm asking you. I've only just started using Funcs and if someone has any comments for improvement I'll gladly take them into consideration.

Comment: You could create a `Dictionary<string, Func<Vector3, Vector3>>` which maps the strings you display to the user to each function. Then you loop through their choices and do a lookup to find the correct function to execute.

Comment: How would I store the *order* of execution though? First item in dictionary first to be executed, second in dictionary second to be executed and so on?

Comment: To me it feels like you are asking how to fill a list based on user choices - this sounds way too broad for me... but I'm missing something probably.

Comment: I could store a list of user choices, but then my problem would be mapping the choices to the delegates. As @Rob mentioned though, Dictionary would probably be the solution, didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the Func delegates in a class, and I'd define a property on that class representing the order in which you need to execute the Funcs.

Then using Linq's `OrderBy`, you could do something like this:

```
//Defined in some class
protected List<FuncWrapper> Operators { get; set; }

private void CreateFunctors()
{

    Operators.Add(new FuncWrapper { Functor = (v) => v.Z == 0 ? v.Add(1, 0, 1) : v.Subtract(1, 0, 1), Order = 1 });
    Operators.Add(new FuncWrapper { Functor = (v) => v.Z == 0 ? v.Add(2, 0, 1) : v.Subtract(2, 0, 1), Order = 2 });

}

private void CallFunctors()
{
    Vector3 v = new Vector3();

    foreach (var f in Operators.OrderBy(o => o.Order))
        f.Functor(v);
}

//Defined somewhere else
public class FuncWrapper
{
    public Func<Vector3, Vector3> Functor { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

This is just the rough idea. Adapt as needed.

Cheers

Comment: Great idea, I can even bind to properties in the wrapper from my view so user ordering can be done through binding. Thank you so much!

Comment: Right ! I like such scenarios :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

First define the dictionary that maps the names to the functions like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Vector3, Vector3>> Operators = new Dictionary<string, Func<Vector3, Vector3>>()
{
    {"function1_display_name", Move1MFunc},
    {"function2_display_name", Move2MFunc}
};;
```

And then lets say that you collected a `List<string>` that contains the display names of the functions from the user, you can create a list of functions like this:

```
// list_of_names_from_user is the list of function names collected from the user
List<string> list_of_names_from_user = ......

List<Func<Vector3, Vector3>> ordered_functions =
    list_of_names_from_user.Select(x => Operators[x]).ToList();
```

Now `ordered_functions` will contain the functions ordered according to the order of function display names in `list_of_names_from_user`

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary instance `OperatorsWithTypes` and function `GetOrderedOperators` like this:

```
    protected static Dictionary<string, Func<Vector3, Vector3>> OperatorsWithTypes 
    { get; set; }

    public static List<Func<Vector3, Vector3>> GetOrderedOperators()
    {
        return (from category in OperatorWithTypes
            orderby
                category.Key == "First"
                    ? 0
                    : category.Key == "Second"

                        ? 1
                        : category.Key == "Third"

                            ? 2
                            : category.Key == "Forth"

                                ? 3
                                : category.Key == "5th"

                                    ? 4
                                    : category.Key == "6th"
                                        ? 5
                                        : -1
            select category.Value)
            .ToList();
    }
```

and call it:

```
foreach (var op in GetOrderedOperators())
    {
        // Get a child using the current operator
        var possibleChild = op(parentState);
        ...
```